# Really Long Sum for a probablity question

Tags: combinatorics, summation

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(k\binom nk\left(\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{k+i}\binom ki i^n\right)\right)$$

I know this is the right answer because I approximated this for $n=1000$ and the app said answer is close but not near enough to accept. It needs 6 digits of precesion or exact answer. It's about $0.632$. How do I solve this summation.

Here's the exact question for anyone wondering

> You are given a collection of $N$ distinct objects from which you draw a random sample of size $N$ with replacement — that means objects are allowed to be sampled multiple times. Generating a sample in this way is related to the statistical technique called bootstrapping.
>   We're interested in the expected fraction of the original collection that ends up in the sample (i.e. the probability that a given object in the original collection appears at least once in the sample). What does this probability converge to as $N$ goes to infinity?

Comment: Since you gave the 1st 3 digits as 0.632, I suspect that the answer is $1 - 1/e.$ I will try to prove this.

Comment: How did you get to this monstrous limit of sums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner sum is associated to the application of the $k$-th power of the [forward difference operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) to the polynomial $z^n$. In particular the inner sum is $k!{n\brace k}$, with ${n\brace k}$ being a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). So we have to deal with
$$ \frac{1}{n^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}k!{n\brace k}\tag{1}$$
where
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{x}{n}k!{n\brace k} = x^n \tag{2}$$
and $k\binom{n}{k} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ for any $k,n\geq 1$. Thus the written limit is
$$ 1-\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = 1-\frac{1}{e}.$$

Answer (score 4):

The probability that a given object is *not* drawn is $\left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^N=\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^N$.
The probability that a given object *is* drawn is then simply
$1-(\frac{N-1}{N})^N=1-\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^N$. The limit as $N$ goes to infinity is a standard limit, and evaluates to
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}1-\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^N=1-\frac{1}{e}.$$

Comment: Wow... The clue said something like this but I couldn't connect the dots... Since on avg an object gets selected 0.632 times thus that is the fraction of objects being selected. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: At this point you might want to use the definition of expected value to compute the expected fraction.